# Cards stacking over one another with the grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 4 cards using bootstrap 4.  However, when I scale down, the 4 cards overlap one another instead of going down to 2, then to 1 on mobile view.

My code: https://codepen.io/jehc10/pen/LKqRRQ

```css
.navbar-nav {
  background: #4287f5;
}

.navbar-brand {
  background: #4287f5;
}

.navbar-brand.custom {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 25px
  /* border-right:2px solid black; */
}

.navbar {
  background: #4287f5;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("attractive-backdrop-background-988872.jpg");
  /* font-weight:700; */
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

form {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- My stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">

    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Jesse</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- NAV bar -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand custom" href="#">Jesse</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Portfolio cards -->
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-sm-3>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="cat.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=col-sm-3>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="cat.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=col-sm-3>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="cat.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=col-sm-3>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="cat.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contact form -->
    <div class=row>
        <div class=col-lg-6>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline fixed width to solve this issue.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
```

Comment: While that does prevent them from overlapping now, the button is not changing sizes and the words are getting squeezed down to single characters when i scale.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some classes in your card and it will solve your problem.

```
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 mb-3">
      <div class="card w-100">
        <img src="cat.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It should solve the problem.

I added **col-12** in card wrapper and **w-100** in card for full width.
removed the inline style width from the card.

Comment: This gets it done to 1 on mobile version, but still 4 on tablet view (whereas it should be 2 columns).

Comment: replace **col-12 col-sm-3** with **col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3**

Comment: For more details about grid view this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 0):

First don't set the width inline with `style="width: 18rem;"` or in a css file. The width should be determined by the `col-x` classes of Bootstrap. That is kind of the whole idea.

And if you want to put them below each other you can do this `col col-sm-6 col-lg-3`. Meaning a card will take up full width on XS, 2 next to each other from SM to MD and 4 next to each other on LG and XL

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does fix the issue, however for whatever reason, it goes to one full width around tablet size, then back to 2 on mobile size.

Comment: Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/. You can specify how many colums per specific width. You may need to tweak it for your cards. It could be that 2 don't fit side by side on tablet so it goed back to one row again.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the `col-sm-3` from the parrent your should work just fine. 
What is happening is that you force the parrent div's to fit in one line. But inside them you have a div with a fixed with `style="width: 18rem;"`. So the inner div doesn't fit in the parrent div. That is why they are overlapping (and the `flex-wrap` property is not working as it should).

Comment: Also the button is not changing its size because the with of the button has the with of the text and the withespace is set to no wrap(so the text will always be in one line). You can read more about the no-wrap property here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space .

Comment: I am a bit confused, as I never entered no-wrap....where would I change it in the code?

Comment: To the anchor tag that has the `class="btn btn-primary"`. So for example you could add a css rule like this 
`a.normal-white-space {
  white-space: normal;
}`
than add the class to your button (so for example `<a href="http://www.google.ca" class="btn btn-primary normal-white-space ">Go somewhere</a>`).  Keep in mind that only `.normal-white-space {...}` wouldn't work because it would be overwritten by bootstrap btn class.